# Is there a way to get State Management working for Abstract Compose View in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, ime

I'm currently creating a keyboard that needs to be able to get Data from a View Model that I've created.

The problem arises to the fact that the Keyboard is not able to be recomposed when any type of state is changed.

Is there a way to be able to implement recomposes/updates as any state is changed for the Abstract Compose View?

For reference this is the code I'm using for the InputMethodService

```
class IMEService:
    InputMethodService(),
    LifecycleOwner,
    ViewModelStoreOwner,
    SavedStateRegistryOwner {
    private val _lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry by lazy { LifecycleRegistry(this) }
    private val _store by lazy { ViewModelStore() }
    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = _lifecycleRegistry
    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore = _store
    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this).savedStateRegistry
    private fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) =
        _lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)

    @CallSuper
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // You must call performAttach() before calling performRestore(Bundle)
        savedStateRegistry.performAttach(lifecycle)
        savedStateRegistry.performRestore(null)
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        stopSelf()
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }

    lateinit var viewModel: RepoViewModel
    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val app = (application as Nitroless)
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, RepoViewModelFactory(app.repository, app.communityReposRepository)).get(RepoViewModel::class.java)

        this.attachToDecorView(
            window?.window?.decorView
        )
        return view
    }

    fun attachToDecorView(decorView: View?) {
        if (decorView == null) return

        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
        decorView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this)
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added the View Model as a Provider onCreateInputView() function. The problem is not that I'm not able to access it, the problem is I can't seem to update the ComposeKeyboardView.

Here's my ComposeKeyboardView -

```kotlin
class ComposeKeyboardView(context: Context): AbstractComposeView(context) {
    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        val viewModel: RepoViewModel = (context as IMEService).viewModel

        KeyboardScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Since composable holding a state can recompose when the state changes, you need to think of a state object. 
The `viewModel` in `Content` is not a mutable state, since it is initialised once.

Comment: Even trying a `by remember { mutableStateOf() }` doesn't recompose inside AbstractComposeView, or maybe it doesn't work for Services, just Views, since I'm trying to make a keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I was looking at the Docs for InputMethodService and found setInputView(View: View?), this way I can force refresh the compose view onto the keyboard.

So I just do

`(context as IMEService).setInputView(ComposeKeyboardVie(context))`

I also found a way to use Hilt inside the IMEService class, by using `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation for the Service and using `@Inject` annotation to inject the View Model.

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class IMEService:
    InputMethodService(),
    LifecycleOwner,
    ViewModelStoreOwner,
    SavedStateRegistryOwner {
    private val _lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry by lazy { LifecycleRegistry(this) }
    private val _store by lazy { ViewModelStore() }
    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = _lifecycleRegistry
    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore = _store
    override val savedStateRegistry: SavedStateRegistry = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this).savedStateRegistry
    private fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) =
        _lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)

    @CallSuper
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // You must call performAttach() before calling performRestore(Bundle)
        savedStateRegistry.performAttach(lifecycle)
        savedStateRegistry.performRestore(null)
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        stopSelf()
    }

    @CallSuper
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var repoViewModel: RepoViewModel

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)

        this.attachToDecorView(
            window?.window?.decorView
        )
        return view
    }

    fun attachToDecorView(decorView: View?) {
        if (decorView == null) return

        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
        decorView.setViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner(this)
    }
}
```

And inside the App Module I just added

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Provides
fun providesRepoViewModel(repoDatabaseDao: RepoDatabaseDao, communityReposRepository: CommunityReposRepository) = RepoViewModel(repository = RepoRepository(repoDatabaseDao), communityReposRepository = communityReposRepository)
```